# Access GoogleMap object of one Activity in another Activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I extend my app with google map activity. it created a mapclass and extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback.

the onMapReadyCallBack return GoogleMap object as below code.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    public GoogleMap mMap;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

I want to access mMap on my MainActivity class to do some operation. i create a button with onclick attribute to gotolocation method. but it return error becuase the map object is null; which is the proper way to access the GoogleMap object in my activity class.

```
public void gotoLocation(View v){
    if (mMap != null){
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Kabul"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }else{
        Log.d("Map object", "It si null==============");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that only one Activity at a time can be shown to the user, so there is no need to access the `mMap` variable from MainActivity.

Assuming you want to open up MapsActivity when the `gotoLocation()` button is clicked, you can pass the data associated with the location from MainActivity over to MapsActivity.

First, prepare the LatLng and description in MainActivity in order to send it to MapsActivity when the button is clicked:

```
public void gotoLocation(View v){
  LatLng goToLocation = new LatLng(34.5392354, 69.1378334);

  Bundle args = new Bundle();
  args.putParcelable("latLon", goToLocation);
  args.put("desc", "Marker in Kabul");

  Intent i = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
  i.putExtras(args);
  startActivity(i);
}
```

Then, when MapsActivity is opened, it will retrieve the info, and modify the Marker accordingly:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    public GoogleMap mMap;
    LatLng mLatLng; 
    String mDescription;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);

        //Get the data sent from MainActivity
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        mLatLng = intent.getParcelableExtra("latLon");
        mDescription = intent.getStringExtra("desc");

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        //Use the data sent from MainActivity:
        if (mLatLng != null) {
          // Add a marker for location/description sent from MainActivity
          mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mLatLng).title(mDescription));
          mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mLatLng));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Danial i am agree with you this way it works but the map is a fragment and it is placed inside user content xml of navigation bar. I am trying to get input from user in Navigation class and chand the map location.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to first answer, the `mMap` object is null because it is yet to be instantiated and `onMapReady` callback has not yet been called.

take a look at the docs for `OnMapReadyCallback` interface https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback

Comment: How can i instantiate it. The map class is extending fragementactivity and it should be placed in a separate file.